# How to have search box between brand and menu toggle in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to have search bar between brand and menu toggle on mobile view, but search always appears on a seperate row either under or over navbar. I guess I need to override some Bootstrap CSS, but I couldn't find anything.

http://www.bootply.com/0I0LXI5JeE

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/0I0LXI5JeE Sorry, but basically like this. It is all messed up on small screen.

Comment: Add your search box inside `navbar-brand`, it will appears beside brand. Then add some padding or margin for better style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your CSS a lot of this is guess work.  This is by no means the only way to do this but this will get the job done.

First, wrap your brand, search and menu toggle inside your navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand"></a>
    <form class="navbar-form"></form>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle"></a>
</nav>
```

Second, make sure your navbar is wide enough to display your brand, search, and menu toggle on the same line.

```
.navbar {
    width: 100%;    // for example
}
```

Lastly, you have a few options for arranging them on the same line.  All will work.  See what works best for you.

Option #1:

```
.navbar {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-form,
.dropdown-toggle {    
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;   // each element will have equal horizontal width
}
```

Option #2:

```
.navbar {
    display: table;
}
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-form,
.dropdown-toggle {    
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Option #3:

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;    // this will center them vertically
}
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-form,
.dropdown-toggle {    
    flex: 1;    // each element will have equal horizontal width
}
```